# Java += operator "stops adding after certain number"

Tags: java

+= produces different results see the below code ... code with temp works properly not the other  you can debug this by creating a java app.

```
public long JavaStopsAdding(int treeHeight) {

    long cars = 0;
    long cars1 = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (treeHeight - i >= 0) {

        long temp = 0;

        if (treeHeight - i == 0 ) {
            cars += 1;
            cars1 += 1;
            break;
        }


       // working code start

           temp = (long) ((Math.pow(2,treeHeight- i))/2);
       cars1 += temp;
           System.out.print("temp " + (treeHeight- i) + " cars " + cars1 +"\n");
    // working code END

          // NON working code Start
            cars += ((Math.pow(2,treeHeight- i))/2);
    System.out.print("temp " + (treeHeight- i) + " cars " + cars + "\n");   
        // NON working code END
        i += 2;     
    }
    return cars;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by stops ? What is the i/p and expected o/p ?

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: did you try `cars +=(long) ((Math.pow(2,treeHeight- i))/2);` ?

Comment: When it looks like the plus `+` operator stopped adding and started "subtracting", it's "integer overflow".

Comment: Without more detail, I can only guess perhaps you are having numeric overflow? It would explain why casting to a long eliminates the problem. What is the input to this function?

Comment: Well this is clearly a bug in the language, if not mathematics itself.

Comment: can you give a sample run of output? This way, we can find out if numeric overflow has occurred.

Comment: `you can debug this by creating a java app.` Since it's your program can you provide the code which demonstrate the problem?

Comment: You need `BigInteger`, not `long`.

Comment: Doubt highly you discovered an issue with the `+=` operators

Comment: Aw man, disappointment. I thought the lefthand operand would be a `float` or `double` with a large magnitude.

Comment: william-morrison yes william ... why casting is working is my question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely there is nothing wrong with +=.  Instead the problem is your value is overflowing.

You shouldn't be using `Math.pow(2, n)`, instead use `1L << n` which is not only faster but more likely to work.  Either way, you cannot have n > 62 and expect this to work.

Comment: And the larger `n` is, the lower the `k` will be before `n << k` begins to fail for you. If `n == 1` you get have a `k` of up to `62` and still be peachy. If `n == 4`, then your `k` will only be `60`. Perhaps OP should consider `BigInteger`?

Comment: @corsiKa or a BitSet to set the n-th bit.

Comment: you are correct , but why will that overflow ? with temp is working but not Math directly ... what is the funda behind this...

Comment: The difference is that `a += b` where `b` is a `double` is the same as `a = (long) ((double) a + b)`  This chops off the lower bits of the long as the double only has 53-bits of precision where as long has 64-bits.

Answer (score 1):

Use BigInteger as the math operation causing it to overflow.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested the code with treeheight = 10 and find everything normal. your code contain two variable cars1 and cars :

```
// working code start

temp = (long) ((Math.pow(2,treeHeight- i))/2);
cars1 += temp;
System.out.print("temp " + (treeHeight- i) + " cars " + cars1 +"\n");
// working code END

 // NON working code Start
        cars += ((Math.pow(2,treeHeight- i))/2);
System.out.print("temp " + (treeHeight- i) + " cars " + cars + "\n");   
    // NON working code END
```